# Accessing the value of this within dragulaService.setOptions

Tags: angular

I define `active` in my class. I would like to access the value of `active` within my Dragula code. When I `console.log` my `this.active` I get `undefined`. It seems that at this point of my code `this` refers to my Dragula object and not the variables I have declared at the start of my class.

How can I access the value of `active` within my Dragula code?

```
export class GamePage {

  active = [];
  inactive = []; 

  constructor() {

    this.dragulaService.setOptions('drop-'+this.tableID, {
      revertOnSpill: true, 
      direction: 'horizontal',
      moves: (el, source, handle, sibling) => this.checkPlayerCanBeDragged(el.id),
      accepts: function (el, target, source, sibling) {

        console.log('inactive', this.inactive);

        return true;

      }      
    });  

  }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch

Comment: TL;DR: define accepts through a fat arrow function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of your "this" in the function is different from the one in the class. You need to bind the "this" either with Javascript's bind method or a callback:

```
function (el, target, source, sibling) {

    console.log('inactive', this.inactive);

    return true;

  }.bind(this);
```

or

```
   function (el, target, source, sibling, () => {

    console.log('inactive', this.inactive);

    return true;

  });
```

Comment: That's great - I was reading through the comments that were made on my original question and trying to decipher what to do. Your suggestion works perfectly, thank you.